# Using a integer obtained from a database and using it to retrieve some data from database using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC application in which I retrieved a CompanyId which of type int and with that I would like to retrieve more data from the database using LINQ and I using the following code to do that

```
var companyId = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                               .Select(u => u.CompanyId);
return db.CCUserHorizontals.Where(ccu=>companyId.Equals(ccu.CPId));
```

I retrieved `companyId` from UserProfile and using it to compare it with `CPID`

But, when I loaded the page, it threw me an error as follows

```
<m:message>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
</m:message>
<m:type>System.InvalidOperationException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace/>
<m:internalexception>
<m:message>
Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
</m:message>
<m:type>System.NotSupportedException</m:type>
```

**May I know a fix to this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query would return a `IQueryable<int>`, it will be a collection of integer values, *(Which may contain only one/single value)*. Later You are trying to use that in your query and getting the error.

Your code should be like:

```
var companyId = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                               .Select(u => u.CompanyId)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
return db.CCUserHorizontals.Where(ccu => ccu.CPId == companyId);
```

Couple of things to note:

- You can use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`, since `FirstOrDefault` also takes predicate

Like:

```
var item = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
int companyId = 0;
if(item != null) companyId = item.CompanyId;
```

- You may/*(or may not)* call `ToList` on the return value to materialize the query. If your `DataContext` gets disposed in the method then you will get an exception accessing the result of the method in the caller.